# Create a tag cloud in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, user-controls, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.8

I'm trying to create a tag cloud control in windows phone. The tags are just styled buttons. A vertically oriented stackpanel currently holds the buttons.

I am looking for an alternate container that can hold the button flexible, i.e. allow buttons to stack horizontally and then move to the next line when they stop fitting in one line. Each button is variable in width.

Any suggestions of the best way to do this? Solutions compatible with Windows Phone 7 please.

Comment: Sounds like `WrapPanel` would be your friend.

Comment: Wow. Helps! could you add this as an answer so I could mark it?

Comment: Sure, why not. As answer below, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for a control that will allow its children to take up what space they can and then automatically wrap the overflow to the next line(s) the [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) control available in the toolkit makes it a pretty painless and easy chore.

Hope this helps, cheers!